Given a matrix with i.i.d. Gaussian entries compute the norm of the matrix vector product
I have been working through this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.17813
I was trying to prove the attached statement.
Let $W \in \mathbb{R}^{n_{\ell} \times n_{\ell-1}}$ with  i.i.d. entries sampled from a Gaussian distribution $N(0, \sigma_{\ell})$. Let $h \in \mathbb{R}^{n_{\ell-1}}$ with $\|h\| = k\sqrt{n_{\ell-1}}$ for some constant $k>0\in \mathbb{R}$. Then, apparently it follows from the law of large numbers that $\|W h\| \approx \sigma_{\ell}\sqrt{n_{\ell}} \|h\|$.
However, I don't see it. I attached a picture of my derivation as well. In my derivation I made a brutal simplifying assumption and said $h_i = c$ for $i = 1, \dots, n_{\ell-1}$ with $c > 0$.
Thank you for your help!
Best,
Chris

I would give the following explanation.
For simplicity of notation I assume $\mathbf{W}\in\mathbb{R}^{n_l \times n_{l-1}}$ with $w_{ij}\sim N(0,\sigma_l)$
$$\|\mathbf{W}\mathbf{h}\|_2^2 = \mathbf{h}^T\mathbf{W}^T\mathbf{W}\mathbf{h} = \mathbf{h}^T\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{h} = \sum_{i,j}q_{ij}h_ih_j$$
where $\mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{W}^T\mathbf{W}$. Let's compute $q_{ij}$ with the Law of Large Numbers. Then:
$$q_{ij} = (\mathbf{W}^T\mathbf{W})_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^{n_l}w_{ki}w_{kj}$$

If $i\neq j$ every term in the above expression has expected value $0$ and therefore the sum has expected value $0$. From the law of large numbers, as $n_l$ grows large we have with probability $1$:
$$q_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^{n_l}w_{ki}w_{kj} \to n_l\cdot 0 = 0$$

Otherwise, if $i=j$ then the above is equal to $q_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^{n_l}w_{ki}^2$. Then, each $w_{ki}^2$ is the square of a normal variable and has expected value equal to $\sigma_l^2$ (see this post). Then from law of large numbers we derive:
$$q_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^{n_l}w_{ki}^2 \to n_l\cdot \sigma_l^2$$


From the above observations we derive the result, namely:
$$\|\mathbf{W}\mathbf{h}\|_2^2  = \sum_{i,j}q_{ij}h_ih_j \to \sum_{i}n_l\sigma_l^2h_i^2 = n_l\sigma_l^2\|\mathbf{h}\|_2^2$$

$q_{ij}\rightarrow n_l\cdot\sigma_l^2$ as $n_l\rightarrow\infty$ is not a good notation
